# Query the join several tables once or several queries?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, performance, for-loop

I have to make the bundle of the data from 4 *(or more)* tables.
And as I known there are 2 ways to deal with.

- Join all of them on the database then query once.
- Query once per table then manage/combine them on the backend.

Even the first way seems more reasonable somehow,
If they *(any rows from join-result)* have the same parent *(parent-key(s))*,
the data from joining the tables still need to be grouped together.

For example.

```
// foos and bars from separately query
foos: [ { foo_id: 1, ...(foo1) }, { foo_id: 2, ...(foo2) } ];
bars: [
 { foo_id: 1, bar_id: 1, ...(bar1) },
 { foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2, ...(bar2) },
 { foo_id: 2, bar_id: 3, ...(bar3) },
 { foo_id: 2, bar_id: 4, ...(bar4) }
];

// foo-bars from the join-result using foo_id as join-key
foo_bar: [
 { foo_id: 1, ...(foo1), bar_id: 1, ...(bar1) },
 { foo_id: 1, ...(foo1), bar_id: 2, ...(bar2) },
 { foo_id: 2, ...(foo2), bar_id: 3, ...(bar3) },
 { foo_id: 2, ...(foo2), bar_id: 4, ...(bar4) }
];
```

Should be grouped/combined as

```
foos: [
 {
  foo_id: 1,
  ...(foo1),
  bars: [
   { bar_id: 1, ...(bar1) },
   { bar_id: 2, ...(bar2) },
  ]
 },
 {
  foo_id: 2,
  ...(foo2),
  bars: [
   { bar_id: 3, ...(bar3) },
   { bar_id: 4, ...(bar4) },
  ]
 },
];
```

and so on for other remains tables...

So, No matter how I query, The data still require to be managed on the backend.

Therefore At present, I have chosen the second way to implement.
(but still looking for better ways to deal with, and plan to change if necessary)

I have grouped them with declare new object using the key of parent to be key pair up with itself as value to avoid searching with nested for-loop.

```
const arrayToObject = (array, key) => {
  const object = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    object[array[i][key]] = array[i];
  }

  return object;
};
```

So my bundle for-loop looks like..

```
const bundling = async() => {
 // foo.fetch() & bar.fetch() is models that
 // call db.query('SELECT * FROM foo/bar')

 const [rawFoo, rawBar] = await Promise.all([foo.fetch(), bar.fetch()]);
 const foos = arrayToObject(rawFoo, 'foo_id');

 // create blank child list in each parent
 for (let i = 0; i < rawFoo.lenght; i += 1) {
  rawFoo[i].bars = [];
 }

 // this similar to nested for-loop that
 // outer iteration is pointing to each parent member
 // and inner one is pointing to each child member
 // then check if they have same parent key >> do something

 for (let i = 0; i < rawBar.length; i += 1) {
  foos[ rawBar[i].foo_id ].bars.push( rawBar[i] );
 }

 return rawFoo;
}
```

According to another question,
[Which is more expensive? For loop or database call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390757/which-is-more-expensive-for-loop-or-database-call)
There is an overhead of connection to the database that will cause my current solution worse than the another.

But the second-top-answer of [JOIN queries vs multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067016/join-queries-vs-multiple-queries) made me confused which one better when I think about the join output size compare with sum-size of each query.

Examples for sql code

```
# join table
# note that child table has parent id

SELECT * FROM foo
 LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id
 LEFT JOIN baz ON bar.bar_id = baz.bar_id
 LEFT JOIN qux IN baz.baz_id = qux.baz_id

# several query for manage on backend

SELECT * FROM foo;
SELECT * FROM bar;
SELECT * FROM baz;
SELECT * FROM qux;
```

the table structure of each table is similar to each other.

each table consists 3 main parts: `parent_id, own_id, ...other_props`

The number of other_props

- foo: ~ 15-20 fields
- bar: < 15 fields
- baz: < 10 fields
- qux: < 10 fields

Comment: I don't see any SQL code here or table structure.  You should rephrase your question by showing us what is happening first on your database.  Then, afterwards worry about JavaScript.