# Insert multiple records in mysql using node.js fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to INSERT multiple records in a MySQL Table, but whatever I do, it inserts only one row.

Here is the node.js code:

```
let orderID = 15; //It is a foreign key. Noted it from the table. 
itemParams = [
        [ orderID, 'd', 34.6, '12', '123.jpeg' ],
        [ orderID, 'd', 30.6, '2', '456.jpeg' ]
];

let addOrderItems = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO orderitems (oid, description, weight, quantity, image_url) VALUES (?)`, itemParams);
```

When I console log addOrderItems the affectedRows count is 1, so I also checked my table in Workbench to be sure and only one row was added. (oid is a foreign key). Table does have a primary key which auto increments.

The query I found online didn't have paranthesis around the question mark ? but when I remove the paranthesis, I get the following error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '19, 'd', 34.6, '12', '123.jpeg'' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (Z:\Jura_SaaS\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at Z:\Jura_SaaS\routes\order.js:190:44
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '19, 'd', 34.6, '12', '123.jpeg'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO orderitems (oid, description, weight, quantity, image_url) VALUES 19, 'd', 34.6, '12', '123.jpeg';"
}
```

NOTE: I have promisified pool.query that is the reason you don't see the callback format of it.

Comment: Please note that ```mysql``` is an older npm package. Use ```mysql2```.
You can refer this link, I had solved before.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464555/unnesting-node-database-calls/65138795#65138795

Comment: First off, you might've to look into changing ```values(?)``` to ```values(?,?....)```

Comment: Okay, I'll try using mysql2 first, but you put only one question mark when you're inserting an array of arrays

Comment: Why is it so? I had tried with one question mark and I had similar problems

Comment: You add multiple question marks (as many as the fields) when you are inserting one tuple/row. If you want to INSERT multiple tuples, you will provide a list of list, so the lists will be related to the question marks and not the items in the list, this is my conclusion after some trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have been using a similar method. Except the fact that I don't insert all the rows at once but execute insertion of each row by executing query in each iteration of a loop.

Note: I'm using MVC server architecture

Here's the code.

1. Controller

```
module.export.multiInsert = async (req) => {
    const transferData = req.body.rows;
    let conn = await con.getConnection();

    for await (data of transferData) {
    try {
            await conn.beginTransaction();
           // code for insertion
            const data = await something.addData(conn, a, b, c);
    } catch (error) {
            conn.rollback();

            response.status = false;
            response.result = 'Error occured!'

            console.log(error)

    } finally {
            conn.release();
    }
}
```

2. Model

```
Class something{
static async addData(conn, a, b, c) {

        let params = [a,b,c];

        const [resData] = await conn.execute('INSERT INTO `table` (`a`,`b`,`c`) 
                          VALUES(?,?,?);', params);
        return { "status": resData };
    }
}
```

3. Route

```
router.post('/insert-a-lot-of-data', controller.multiInsert)
```

Comment: This looks good but Isn't it expensive? Querying the database again and again?

Comment: according to [11718292](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390762/11718292) it is better if you can reduce the number of calls to your database

Comment: I ended up using multiple calls to the database as the bulk insert didn't work out for me

Comment: There is an alternate way but I'm not sure if that's right. What we can do is dynamically create the insert query by appending all the parameters in a loop and just execute it.
I have not tried it though

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but then that would just become messy won't it? But I think it might be efficient

Comment: Yes, I'll be giving it a  shot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is an [article](https://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/insert-multiple-records-into-mysql-using-nodejs) detailing your case. For your case I would do the following :

```
let orderID = 15; //It is a foreign key. Noted it from the table. 
itemParams = [
        [ orderID, 'd', 34.6, '12', '123.jpeg' ],
        [ orderID, 'd', 30.6, '2', '456.jpeg' ]
];

let addOrderItems = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO orderitems (oid, description, weight, quantity, image_url) VALUES ?`, [itemParams]);
```